# Java programs not running in terminal

Tags: fedora, terminal, java

I have java 8 installed on fedora 20.
Any java program  runs perfectly fine via eclipse but when I run the same program on terminal it reports an error saying 'could not load main class' . what could be the problem?

I wrote a simple helloworld program named hello.java and executed on eclipse. Then I opened terminal and moved to the folder containing the hello.class in eclipse workspace and typed ' java hello '. But it said 'error:could not load main class'.

Also as I said I have installed and I use oracle java 8.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! You need to give a little more detail: what command are you typing to start your program? Please [edit] your question to add the info.

Comment: Could you please paste the code of your Hello.java file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open it with `java -jar Hello`

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error: unable to access jarfile  Hello

Comment: Have you given the file execute permission?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type java -version and observe the version that appear.

say, it is v1

in eclipse Window->Preferences->Java compiler, check version

say it is v2

To work v2 must be <= v1, if eclipse has newer java version you need one of two:

1) install newer java on linux
2)  downgrade java compiler in eclipse

Comment: Java version at both the places is 1.8 .

Comment: Check that: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: Yeah.... Found the solution. I had to use '-cp . ' option to include the current directory in class path. Surprisingly it java does not even look in the current working directory for .class files. I had to use ' java -cp . Hello' to run the class file.